# Property 'sort' does not exists on type 'number'

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting, numbers

I face this error in my angular projects that doesn't allow me use sort to an array.

[image]

```
   let list = [];
    this.saved = this.db.collection('saved').snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Saved;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        list.push(data.id).sort((stra, strb) => (stra < strb ? -1 : 1));
        return data;
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

[Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) will return new length of array so `list.push(data.id)` will return a number so you need to change your code to

```
list.push(data.id);
list.sort((stra, strb) => (stra < strb ? -1 : 1));
```